# Save a Powerpoint 2013 Presentation as a Webpage

Tags: sharepoint-2010, powerpoint

Up until Powerpoint 2013, we were able to design Sharepoint Webpages / Portals in Powerpoint, hyperlink to images, and save these into Sharepoint as an HTML webpage saved via Microsoft Powerpoint, they have now removed this feature in Powerpoint 2013.  We are in search for a new simple solution for Sharepoint Page design.

Does anybody know a workaround to this issue?  It has grounded our sharepoint updates to a halt, and we don't exactly have access to advanced coders

EDIT:

Its worth mentioning that the tools we have access too are

1. MS Office 2013 Suite
2. Sharepoint Designer 2010
3. Sharepoint 2010
4. Access 2010

Comment: if you're using sharepoint, can't u just use an office web apps server to display the presentations or slideshows directly in sp?

Comment: The problem is, its not a presentation display we are after, we actually develop web content on Powerpoint 2010, we then convert it to HTML.

Comment: I don't have access to ppt2013 right now, have you tried [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/89d70894-b455-4d3e-a801-f2574c3a0f5a/powerpoint-2010-save-as-webpage) method of calling the VB immediate script? it says its for ppt2010 but it might still be in ppt2013

Comment: yes, it blocks that method by saying it has been removed.

Comment: That's correct; in 2010 the ability to save as HTML was removed from the user interface; in 2013, the method was completely removed from the program. There are third-party add-ins and programs that convert PowerPoint to HTML though.  Google PowerPoint to HTML to find several of them.  Disclaimer:  one of them is my PPT2HTML add-in.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible natively in Powerpoint 2013.

Link: [Discontinued or changed features in PowerPoint 2013](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Discontinued-or-changed-features-in-PowerPoint-2013-5DA4D3D4-85EF-4E74-8E9E-511BA59482D5)